# unable to execute python script in php

Tags: php, python, pypi

I am facing problem while retrieving result from python script

my php script as follows:

```
<?php
   $cmd=escapeshellcmd('/opt/lampp/htdocs/adpNews/adpScripts/getArticle.py');
$result=shell_exec("python $cmd");
echo $result;                   
?>
```

my Python script as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from newspaper import Article

url=u'http://www.abplive.in/india-news/countering-terrorism-an-important-shared-objective-by-india-united-states-manohar-parrikar-407134'

article=Article(url)
article.download()
article.parse()
print article.text
```

Please do give me the solution

Comment: remove the `u` after `url=` ?!

Comment: dear freind...I did it but it doesn't worked and the same code if I run it on python console it works, but not with php

Comment: Does you python script work when you call run it manually?

Comment: did you call the php script from console or from web? Maybe you have an rights issue. Because from web you are the user `www-data` and that is not the same user u have under a php script that is run from console.

Comment: Test it `print shell_exec("whoami");`

Comment: dear PhilipB, the above I have specified in python, works well in my ubuntu python console manually...but I am very new and don't know about call run it manually

Comment: Dear friend JustOne... When i run the above statement i.e. print shell_exec("whoami"); --> it gives me result daemon .... AND in my python script if I just write ...print "Hello" ..., then it works and shows Hello on my web page

Comment: Dear Dinesh, your answer doesn't works

Comment: Still my issue is not resolved..can anyone help me.. I'll be highly obliged

Comment: I just want to ask you friends that article I extract from news portal may contain some special characters, so the output may not be achieved... Is it so?